# Hide / remove filter icon on Apache Superset 2.0.1

Tags: css, icons, apache-superset

I am currently customizing the dashboard I created on Apache Superset. The dashboard requires me to remove the existing filter icon for the table (filter icon as refers in the image - top right circle).

[image]

Referring to the articles and references, I know it can be done using the CSS embedded in the superset. However, so far I have only found the one that hides the other features like chart title and table header.

Is there any way to hide the filter icon in generated table on superset? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guys from Preset have a nice blog about customizing Superset dashboards via CSS manipulation: https://preset.io/blog/customizing-superset-dashboards-with-css

You can remove the filter symbols from the charts (together with the chart menus, though) by adding following snippet to the dashboard's CSS:

```
.header-controls {
    display: none !important;
}
```